# Are negative signed integers, converted to binary, simply regular integers +256?

Tags: computer-science, binary

Are negative signed integers, converted to binary, simply regular negative integers +256?

```
00001010 = + 10 signed
00001010 = + 10 unsigned

11110110 = - 10 signed
11110110 = +246 unsigned (-10+256=246)
```

Notice how -10 (signed) is just -10+256=246 (unsigned)?

So in other words: If you want to represent a negative integer (such as -10) as a signed byte, you would simply add 256 before doing the base2 conversion?

I also heard that it can be done by "inverting all the bits and then adding one to the result".

---

PS: If it's not obvious, dealing with numbers isn't a strength of mine. I know that's probably not the case for most of you, but I'm trying to simplify the concept. Please keep that in mind, and if possible (respectfully) try to resist the urge to make it more confusing or complicated.

Comment: There are [different systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) in use. E.g [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and [Ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) .

Comment: Actually, for an integer (as opposed to signed char), you may have to add $4294967296$ or even $18446744073709551616$ instead of $256$ :)

Comment: A microprocessor manual will necessarily illustrate the format for signed integers (of varying "sizes").  Your magic constant 256 suggests you are thinking of signed bytes, but you should be aware that default integers are bigger than that on modern CPUs.

Comment: I think this would be two's complement. I'm not familar with any other. I tried to add a two's complement tag, but there wasn't one.

Comment: You can put "two's complement" in the search box on a MSE web page and get a list of mostly-relevant questions and answers.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen why?

Answer (score 1):

That works for $8-$bit signed integers on a twos' complement machine.  General-purpose computers all use twos' complement these days, but there are programmable logic arrays that use [sign-magnitude.](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch04s11.html)  If you are using a high-level language like C, don't do this yourself, but let the compiler take care of it, because it will work differently for different-sized integer types.  If you are using a language with unlimited sized integers, like python, this system doesn't work at all.

Comment: I don't know anything about that, let's just stick with two's complement for now.

Comment: @tjt263 Well, everything but the remark on sign-magnitude is relevant to twos' complement.

Comment: This isn't really for any particular scenario. I had an exam, and there were some questions I couldn't answer. They were simple conversion and questions. Some involved addition, etc.

Comment: @tjt263 In that context, adding $256$ is correct.